# .eq causing warning. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: scala, jdo, scala-compiler

I'm using JDO with the DataNucleus typesafe query language in Scala. I therefore have code that looks like this:

```
val id: Long = // something
val cand: QDbObject = QDbObject.candidate()
pm.query[DbObject].filter(cand.id.eq(id))...
```

In a nutshell, this runs a query for all the `DbObject`s whose `id` field is equal to `id`. Unfortunately, I get the following warning:

```
NumericExpression[Long] and Long are unrelated: they will most likely 
never compare equal
```

Clearly, the Scala compiler thinks that `NumericExpression[Long]` is using the built-in definition of `eq()`, which is similar to `==`, but since this comes from Java, the `eq()` method has absolutely nothing to do with Scala's `eq()` method.

Is there any way to get rid of the warning? Obviously, this is going to happen a lot and I'm afraid these non-warnings will hide real warnings.

**Update** (2013-06-29)

This was fixed in Scala 2.10.2. The warnings are gone.

Comment: I'd call it a bug. Even if you enclose `eq` in back-ticks (hard to show in a comment, I think...), which is supposed to remove any special meaning the Scala language attaches to any given symbol, you get the same diagnostic.

Comment: Where should I ask if it really is a bug/report it?

Comment: Scala's JIRA is at https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Looks like this is fixed Scala 2.10.2. Or at least that's what the bug report suggests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was more concerned whether the `eq` method would actually be called instead of Scala's `eq`! But it is. I don't think you can get rid of it, though. If you are using Scala 2.10, you can create an implicit value class with a different method calling `eq` -- it will be effectively the same thing, but the warning will be limited to one file.

Comment: How very annoying! Scala needs an equivalent of @SuppressWarnings. I'm going to hold off on giving you a check for a day or two, hoping that someone knows something you don't (which, based on previous answers, isn't likely).

Comment: @TOB: I believe Scala should not generate that warning if the reserved word, `eq`, is enclosed in back-ticks.

Comment: Not generate the warning if the .eq implementation comes from a non-Scala class.